# Right way to iterate a sequence of XML nodes in PHP

Tags: php, xml, magento

Wich is the right way to iterate these pieces of XML?

Hi there.

I have a webservice that brings me some clients to integrate.

If the werbservice returns only one client, the result is like this:

```
 <ClientsToIntegrateResult>
    <Client>
       <Id>1</Id>
       <Name>John</Name>
    </Client>
 </ClientsToIntegrateResult>
```

If the webService returns more than one client, the result is like this :

```
 <ClientsToIntegrateResult>
    <Client>
       <Id>1</Id>
       <Name>John</Name>
    </Client>
    <Client>
       <Id>2</Id>
       <Name>Peter</Name>
    </Client>   
 </ClientsToIntegrateResult>
```

And I have this piece of PHP code to read the results from webService, where $myWSResponse is the instance of my webService :

```
 $clients = $myWSResponse->ClientsToIntegrateResult;

 foreach ($clients->Client as $client ) 
 {
    print_r($client); //Print the client node and its properties if more than one client, and prints each property of client node if only one client.
    print_r($client->Id); //Give me error if only one client, because Id will not exist.
 }
```

My problem is my code doesn't work when webservice returns only one client. 
When I have more than one client my foreach works fine, as I desire, because `$clients->Client` will be a array.
But when the webService returns only one client `$clients->Client` will be the node itself and my code will throw errors.

What can I do to solve it?

I'm not accustomed with PHP development, but with .NET development. Any help will be precious.

Comment: To broad — PHP has myriad objects that represent and deal with XML. We'd need to know what sort of object $myWSResponse is (var_dump( get_class($myWSResponse))) can help you there.

Comment: @AlanStorm the result of `var_dump(get_class($myWSResponse))` is `string(8) "stdClass"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(count($clients->Client) > 1){

foreach ($clients->Client as $client ) 
 {
    print_r($client); //Print the client node and its properties if more than one client, and prints each property of client node if only one client.
    print_r($client->Id); //Give me error if only one client, because Id will not exist.
 }

}else {
echo $clients->Client['id']; //and other child attributes
}
```